# jquery delay anmiations

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, delay

The first `<div>` move down animation works great. I want second `<div>` to slide up after a delay of 500 ms. It is not working right. Does anyone have any idea why?

This works great with out delay:

```
$('#first-div').animate({top:"640px"},3000);
$('#second-div').slideDown("1000");
```

but i want to delay the second `<div>` to slide up after first `<div>` moves down.
but it's not working under `.delay()`

```
$('#first-div').animate({top:"640px"},3000);
$('#second-div').delay(5000).slideup("1000");
```

The complete script I tried using is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $('#first-div').animate({top:"640px"},3000);
      $('#second-div').delay(5000).slideup("1000");
      });
```

The second `<div>` slide up after delay is not working! what did i miss?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: the second div of images slideup is not working

Comment: What does "not working" mean? (Also, I only see `slideDown`.)

Comment: oh im it is slidup not slidedown and still not working using .delay() to slideup, any idea!

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Again, please don't use those words. Instead, say what happens and doesn't happen but was expected. (Using `slideup` will result in an error.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the second action to occur after the first, you can use the `complete` function

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#first-div').animate({top:"640px"}, 3000, function() {
        //executes after the animation completes
        $('#second-div').slideDown("1000");
    });

});
```

**edit**

[Take a look here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more info on `animate`.

Comment: So why doesn't a `delay` work as presented? How do the animation queues work? It's good to *also* explain the issues with the current/presented approach.

Comment: B/c your delay is shorter than the time for the first animation.

Comment: @Michael_B I can only hope that is what "not working" meant =^_^=

Comment: Looks like the delay is shorter.... it may need to be 3000 if that's what he wants to do... this is an alternative possible solution.

Comment: @jwatts1980 The [better] alternative is good. However, also make sure that answers explain why the alternative is better and/or why the original is not sufficient.

Comment: @pst: I'm with you... but I can't explain why it's not working if I don't know what "not working" means. In context, I "assume" he means "thing 2 is not happening after thing 1". And if he wants thing 2 to happen after thing 1, this approach should work for him.

Comment: my code is already show animation is completes but still not slideup the second <div>, so does anyone explain to me what you mean execute after the animation completes !

Comment: at this time using .delay() is not working with slideup,,, any idea!